# I want sum of column having datatype nvarchar in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Here i have table test having column id with datatype nvarchar contains values like
१२३४
२३६८०
४५९०

so i want to do sum of these values.
Basically i want to do manipulation with above numbers. 
please do the needful asap.

Comment: Where are you stuck converting your [Indian numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indic_numerals) into [integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps.

```
declare @T table(id nvarchar(10))

insert into @T values
(N'१२३४'),
(N'२३६८०'), 
(N'४५९०')

select sum(cast(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
         id , N'०', N'0')
            , N'१', N'1')
            , N'२', N'2')
            , N'३', N'3')
            , N'४', N'4')
            , N'५', N'5')
            , N'६', N'6')
            , N'७', N'7')
            , N'८', N'8')
            , N'९', N'9') as int))
from @T
```

Result:

```
(No column name)
29504
```

**Update:**

To be able to reuse this you can create a scalar valued function:

```
create function dbo.DevanagariToInt(@Value nvarchar(10)) returns int
begin
  return cast(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
           @Value
         , N'०', N'0')
         , N'१', N'1')
         , N'२', N'2')
         , N'३', N'3')
         , N'४', N'4')
         , N'५', N'5')
         , N'६', N'6')
         , N'७', N'7')
         , N'८', N'8')
         , N'९', N'9') as int)
end
```

And use it like this:

```
select sum(dbo.DevanagariToInt(ID))
from @T
```

Comment: thanks @mikael is there any code/logic which i can reuse for many table at same time. because here i want to write query for each and every table . So if you have any solution for this problem please reply. thanks & regards mayur vartak

Comment: @Mayur_Vartak - You can create a function that will do the job for you. I have updated the answer.